# Will the thread exit automatically when `func` finishes?

Tags: c, multithreading

Is calling `pthread_exit` explicitly from the thread routine required?

Example code:

```
pthread_create(&pth, NULL, (void *)func, parg);

... func() {
   ...
   //do I have to call pthread_exit() here?
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`pthread_create`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/pthread_create.html) documentation says:

> If the start_routine returns, the effect is as if there was an implicit call to pthread_exit() using the return value of start_routine as the exit status.

So no, no need to call it explicitly.